# visual studio 2013でDLLをビルドするときの質問

Tags: c++, visual-studio

はじめまして、現在Visual Studioを使い簡単なアプリケーションを作っているのですが、一点つまったところがあったので質問させていただきます。

以下のC++で書かれた3ファイルがあります
・app.exe(A.dllを参照)
・A.dll(B.dllを参照)
・B.dll

app.exe+A.dllのみを配布する場合、
Visual Studio 2013でA.dllをビルドするときにB.dllを含めてビルドすることは可能でしょうか。

app.exeには手を加えたくないので、ILMerge以外の方法で探しております。

回答、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ILMergeでは複数のDLLを一つにまとめる機能もありますが、それではだめなんでしょうか？この場合、app.exeは特に変更する必要はないはずです。

Comment: ILMergeが使えるのは.NETアセンブリなので、ネイティブDLLでは使えません。単純な方法はスタティックリンクだと思いますが…B.dllもソースコードをお持ちで、同じくVC++2013でコンパイルしているのでしょうか？

Comment: Sugiyama Koichiさん:ご回答ありがとうございます。もしILMergeで可能であればそれが望ましいですが調べてみたところoutをdllにできないようでしたので、ILMerge以外の方法だと望ましいです

Comment: unarist♦さん：ご回答ありがとうございます。B.dllに関してはヘッダーファイルとdllファイルのみ所持しているのでソースコードは保持していません。またB.dllをコンパイルした環境は分からない状況です。

Comment: なぜ B.dll を配布したくないのか理由がわからないとコメントしづらいっす。ライセンス的に配布できないのであれば「マージして配布」してもライセンス違反でしょうし・・・

Comment: 774RRさん：ご回答ありがとうございます。B.dllは再配布可能なフレームワークなので再配布すること自体は問題ないのですが、それをライセンス表記以外の見える形(dllを含める)で再配布することが御作法として問題がないのであればA.dllに含める必要はないです。
ただB.dllをA.dllに含めることも問題ないのであればそちらの方がdllがごちゃごちゃしないので理想です。

Comment: ちなみにB.dllの具体名は明かせないでしょうか？ 可能なら、で構いませんが。

Answer (score 4):

仮に B.dll が Microsoft の提供しているものだとすると、
その B.dll は `Microsoft Update` で更新されうるものなわけです。
他社 DLL を自作プロダクトに「組み込む」形で配布しちゃうと
Microsoft (だけでなく Apple なり Oracle なりどこであれ) がそれを更新したら、
自作プロダクト側でも組み込み直し、再配布が必要と言うことになりそうです。

「再配布可能なフレームワーク」なんてものは当該メーカ側で用意したインストーラで
一式ごそっと入れちゃうのがお作法だと思います (`vcredist_x86.exe` みたいに) 。
その後のセキュリティ系更新等があっても `Microsoft Update` で更新してね、で済みます。

そもそもオイラ的には EXE と DLL だけ配布するってのはありえなくって
[wix](/questions/tagged/wix) や [installshield](/questions/tagged/installshield) 等でインストーラ作って配布するものだと思います。
自作インストーラが、再配布可能なフレームワークのインストーラを呼ぶのは自然な話、
お作法にかなっている普通の方式です。
あまり凝ったことを考えずにフツーに配布するのが良い、に１票を投じておきます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
インストーラーを呼ぶのが一般的な方法になるんですね。
ありがとうございます！
その方法で実装してみます。

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++の機能としてはありませんが、実現することは可能です。
A.DLLにB.DLLをリンクする時に遅延読み込みに指定しておいて、A.DLLのDllMain等の処理でB.DLLファイル作成すれば実現できるはずです。